# Chrome extension debug inspect popup grayed out

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Chrome Extensions and I'm trying to debug. In chrome://extensions I checked Developer Mode. However, I'm unable to use the "inspect popup" button on my custom chrome extension. It's unusual because I'm able to debug using "inspect popup" on the other chrome extensions on my browser.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Are there any work arounds?

[Heres a screenshot of the "inspect popup"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xHxF.png)

Here is Manifest.json:

```
{
 "name" : "Test",
 "version" : "0.1.0",
 "description" : "get some more images from span data-original, div css 
 computed",
 "permissions": ["contextMenus","tabs","activeTab","<all_urls>"],
 "background": {
 "scripts": ["/dev/js/background.js"]
},
   "content_scripts":[
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "js":["/dev/js/content_scripts.js"],
  "all_frames": false
}],
  "web_accessible_resources":[
  "/dev/view/frame.html",
  "dev/view/grid.html",
  "dev/view/grid.css",
  "dev/view/grid_masonry.css",
  "dev/view/masonry.pkgd.js",
  "dev/view/url",
  "dev/js/grid_masonry.js",
  "dev/view/add.html/*",
  "https://*/*"
],
"browser_action": {
  "default_title":"Add to DB"
}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You're probably using page_action that is not active for the current site, or you've unset the popup via chrome.browserAction.setPopup(). Always add the relevant code in the question e.g. manifest.json in this case.

Comment: Great suggestion. I just uploaded the manifest.json

Comment: There's no `"default_popup"` declaration in the manifest, only the title, hence nothing to inspect.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.